# AMQP Appender pending message count

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We are sending audit log messages to a RabbitMQ cluster which is sometimes unavailable for reasons we cannot influence.

When the queue is not available, log messages start to accumulate locally and we get a out-of-memory eventually on the client.

We are using a [AMQP Appender](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.6.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/logback/AmqpAppender.html) to submit our messages.

Is there a way we can query the count of pending log messages and raise an alert when messages start adding up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it isn't possible. There is just no any hooks to do that.

You can consider, though, to decrease `maxSenderRetries` from default `30` to `1` or `2`. After that you'll start to lose log messages:

```
int retries = event.incrementRetries();
if (retries < AmqpAppender.this.maxSenderRetries) {
    // Schedule a retry based on the number of times I've tried to re-send this
    AmqpAppender.this.retryTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AmqpAppender.this.events.add(event);
            }
        }, (long) (Math.pow(retries, Math.log(retries)) * 1000));
}
else {
    addError("Could not send log message " + logEvent.getMessage()
                + " after " + AmqpAppender.this.maxSenderRetries + " retries", e);
}
```

We might have to expose `queueSize` option instead of default:

```
public LinkedBlockingQueue() {
    this(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) on the matter.